# How can I force ngOnit when an object reference changes?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to create a directive that works similar to ngModel, but will let the input value become out of sync with the bound model.  I know it sounds strange, but The use case is that the bound property could have constraints on it (ie: can't be less than 25), but I want to allow the user to edit the field and not change their value into a constrained one until they are done editing (ngModel will change the value while they are editing, which is annoying).

The problem I'm running into is when the object of the property I'm editing changes, the value in the input that the directive does not.  I'm assuming this is because the directive is bound directly to the primitive of the object, and not the object itself.  What I need is that the directive re-inits when the source parent object changes.

I tried forcing this with *ngIf hoping that it would detect a reference change, and refresh all child components (i'm not sure why I had hoped that) but obviously that doesn't work.

The only way I've been able to get this to work is by first setting the object reference to null (to force the *ngIf re-rendering) and then setting the object to a different reference in a setTimeout.  Obviously this is gross.

Is there a good way to tell Angular that a section of the page needs to refresh if an object reference changes?

Here's a plunker to show the root of my issue (not all of the input editing, etc):  https://plnkr.co/edit/oEeFFLkSMyV0bF4UnEFc?p=preview

And the relevant code from that plunker:

```
interface MyObject{
  value: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

    <div>
      <span>Doesn't Work</span><br>
      <button (click)="changeMyObject(myObject1)">2000</button>
      <button (click)="changeMyObject(myObject2)">3000</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="myObject">    
      <div>
        <h2 [my-sample]="myObject"></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Works with Timeout</span><br>
      <button (click)="changeMyObjectWithTimeout(myObject1)">2000</button>
      <button (click)="changeMyObjectWithTimeout(myObject2)">3000</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  myObject: MyObject;

  private myObject1 : MyObject {
    value: 2000
  };

  private myObject2 : MyObject{
    value: 3000
  }

  constructor() {
    this.myObject = this.myObject1
  }

  changeMyObject(myObject: MyObject){
    this.myObject = myObject;
  }

  changeMyObjectWithTimeout(myObject: MyObject){
    this.myObject = null;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myObject = myObject;
    });
  }
}


@Directive({
  selector: '[my-sample]'
})
export class MySampleDirective implements OnInit{

  @Input('my-sample') myObject : MyObject;

  private _element: any;
  private _differ: KeyValueDiffer;

  constructor(element: ElementRef){
    this._element = element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._element.innerText = this.myObject.value;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
The previous example was maybe too specific to the object reference issue, and without full context isn't clear as to what the issue is, so I'm providing a more comprehensive example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  You can see it here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YecDj100UVUALHHdnRpd?p=preview

The important bits are in the `src\property-value.directive.ts` file.  To re-iterate, the issue is that Angular doesn't (I think rightfully, since I'm not directly binding to it anywhere) recognize the change in object reference, so it doesn't re-init the template.  It was suggested to use OnChanges, which I have tried previously.  The problem with this approach is that Angular doesn't know that the value changed because the parent object is different.  It just knows that it received a new immutable with a different value than the previous one (again, logically that is correct).  So ngOnChanges fires regardless of if you're editing an objects current value, or if you've switched objects.

To recreate the problem i'm having:
Click edit next to myObj1.value and enter a new value
Click edit next to myObj2.value, and you will see that the display value of the input box does not change (b/c ngOnInit doesn't get called).

However, if you click edit next to myObj1.value, edit the value, then click select none so the ngIf removes the element from the DOM, then click edit next to myObj2.value, the ngOnInit method is called, and the display value is correctly set.

I don't want to update the display value in the ngOnChanges method, because at that point i've essentially created a worse version of ngModel (which doesn't solve my use case).

I want the ability for the display model to become out of sync with the backing value while that input has focus (think of it as an edit mode).  The display value in the input will then be updated to match the backing model once the input loses focus, replacing any invalid value the user left (in the supplied example, any value less than 500).

Comment: The only reason it works with the Timeout is because you are assigning null to the property before setting it again. Let me take a look though I might have an idea.

Comment: Right.  It's how I can get the ngIf tag to evaluate and then re-render its template.  I knows there's got to be a proper way of doing this.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook instead of `ngOnInit`. In your example, the reference of the input is changing so the Input property is changing, but the ngOnInit only runs once on load. `ngOnChanges` detects reference changes. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1YU3cUsLwE0RqbaGtEzm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @LLai - I had tried that before, but there is no easy way to differentiate between the actual bound value changing, or the parent object containing the value changing.  I've added a better example in my question to demonstrate what i'm going on about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the feedback combined with the behavior I was seeing with ngIf when I manually null'd the object, it got me thinking about creating a new structural directive.  This is what I came up with:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[boundTo]'
})
export class BoundToDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input('mmBoundTo') boundRef: any;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private 
viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    if(this.boundRef){
       this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(!changes.boundRef.currentValue){
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    } else if(changes.boundRef.previousValue !== changes.boundRef.currentValue){

      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  }
}
```

This will evaluate if an object is the same when it changes, and if it's not, will unload the template, and reload with the new object bound to the template.  This corrects the issue I was having with my property-value directive not updating when an object was switched.  I still don't know if this is the best way, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working. There are couple things wrong here.

1. The only reason it works with the timeout set is because you are destructing your directive and rebuilding it by setting the object to Null before giving it a value again.
2. Your directive is only building the header using ngOnInit(), so if the value changes once it has already been rendered, it's not going to change in the header. NgOnInit only runs once through an elements lifecycle. What you need to do is alter the header within `ngOnChanges()`. That will watch your inputs for changes, and run whatever code you need to run when it detects changes have been made.

**MySampleDirective**

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this._element.innerText = this.myObject.value;
}
```

3. Last but definitely the most tricky is that Javascript passes objects by reference. So using Objects/Arrays in conjunction with Angular's @Input change detection system can be very tricky. Because it won't always detect changes when they occur, which can lead to a lot of headaches downstream. My recommendation for data binding that requires complex data structures beyond your typical string, number, boolean etc. would be to move them to a Service. One possible solution is to rebuild the object every time you change it's value.

**MyObject**

```js
changeMyObject(myObject: MyObject){
    this.myObject = Object.assign({}, myObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this, but unfortunately adding the ngOnChanges and Object.assign trick don't solve the problem.  I've added a better example to my question to show the specific problem i'm trying to solve, and how the lack of object change detection is contributing to my problem.

Comment: That's weird when I made these changes in the plunker it started working as expected.

Comment: [This one](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ioMohtdmx6ptBgKA7I2?p=preview) should work as expected.